# Restructuring a directory of python scripts for easier use in another package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a non-python model with several python scripts in `scripts` sub-directory. If we use the model in a project, we usually clone it into a `model` sub-directory of the project.
This works, but it means that the python scripts have to be called as

```
python model/scripts/do_something.py <ARGS>
```

Also note that the python scripts expect to find the model at `../`, relative to their location.

I want to simplify the usage by making a pip-installable python package that would install one binary (entry point) called `hyopt`, so all the common actions could be done as `hyopt <ACTION> <ARGS>`.

To be able to access the python scripts from the new wrapper, I have landed on the following structure of the python project:

```
│   pyproject.toml
│   README.md
└───src
    └───hyopt
        │   hyopt_cli.py
        ├───model
        │   │   <model files>
        │   └───scripts
        │       │   <python scripts>
```

There, `hyopt_cli.py` is the new wrapper and `model` directory includes the existing code as a git submodule.
This structure allows me to run the existing scripts as a subprocess, using `importlib.resources` to locate them from `hyopt_cli.py`.

However, I would prefer to access some functions and methods in the python files directly from `hyopt_cli.py` and there I encountered the following problem:
Let's say I have three python files there, including (between other) the following:

```py
# foo.py

class Foo:
    ...
```

```py
# bar.py

from foo import Foo

def run_model(args):
    ...
```

```py
# runner.py

from bar import run_model
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
...
args = parser.parse_args()
run_model(args)
```

Here, I can run `runner.py` from `hyopt_cli.py` using `subprocess.run()`, but I would prefer to call `run_model()` directly. However, doing

```py
from .model.scripts.bar import run_model
```

fails with  **`No module named 'foo'`**.

I am still new to python packaging, but I believe this is because the `scripts` directory is not a *package* in the python sense, but rather a collection of python files (mostly scripts, with some files defining common classes etc). It does not have `__init__.py`, either.

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597), I found that I can make it work by adding the following to `hyopt_cli.py`, *before* any import from the `scripts` directory:

```py
import sys
from importlib import resources

script_dir = (resources.files('hyopt.model.scripts') / 'runner.py').parent
sys.path.append(str(script_dir))
```

The " `/ 'runner.py').parent`" part could be skipped if I added `__init__.py` to the `scripts` folder (without it, `resources.files()` returns `MultiplexedPath` which cannot be converted to string).

While this works, it feels more like a hack than a solution. Is there a more pythonic way to make the importing from `hyopt_cli.py` work, without affecting the current functionality of the existing model package? In other words, it should still be possible to use the existing repo without the new python wrapper and call the existing scripts with the same syntax as before (as shown above).

Actually, I am willing to drop the 'same syntax' requirement, if it makes the solution easier/clearner/more pythonic.